# Why expanded view is not being shown

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying out flutter, here I am having a simple card view, where there is an add AddButton , when the button is pressed new card is being added.
Now, i wanted to have it scrollable so added ListView and an expanded Widget in the Column. Here is the code...

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './products.dart';
import './product_control.dart';

class ProductManger extends StatefulWidget {
  final String startingProduct;
  ProductManger({this.startingProduct = "Sweet Tester"});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ProductManagerState();
  }
}

class _ProductManagerState extends State<ProductManger> {
  List<String> _products = ['Food Tester'];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _products.add(widget.startingProduct);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _addProducts(String product) {
    setState(() {
      _products.add(product);
    }); 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Column(children: [ 
      Container(margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0), child: ProductControl(_addProducts)),
      Expanded(child: Products(_products))
    ]);
  }
}
```

If I change that **Expanded** to **Container** with height, it works as expected, but now, nothing is being displayed except  a button.
I am currently following a tutorial, exact same code is written, however, version of flutter is 0.3.2 and i am using 1.5
Or there could be some issue with the emulator?
Hope this helps.

Here is the listView code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Products extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> products;

  Products([this.products = const []]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
        children: products
            .map((element) => Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset('assets/food.jpg'),
                      Text(element)
                    ],
                  ),
                ))
            .toList());
  }
}
```

This is what is visible[image] when i use **Container** with height 300.0 insted to expand

And when i use expand, this is what being shown
[image]

Comment: Where're you using ``ListView`` ?

Comment: Its in another file, posting it now

Comment: Any thoughts ???

Comment: Actually nothing seems to be wrong with your code

Comment: Thats what bugging me out, let me change the emulator, can it be the reason ?

Comment: Try hot reloading maybe it stucks

Comment: In debug, its saying size is missing

Comment: `Container(margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0), child: ProductControl(_addProducts)),` Is this code what you mean by the only button being displayed?

Comment: Yes, the button was being displayed, it seems after hot reloading its gone @MichaelYuwono

Comment: how many products do you have in `products` list? what do you see on the screen if you turn [that](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#visual-debugging) on?

Comment: Just 2 for now, let me turn that on.

Comment: Nothing, is visibal on screen, let me share the screen shots

Comment: what is visibal?

Comment: Just the top app bar :-(

Comment: Problem is i want to make it fit in whole screen using expanded, but its not working, please just bear with me for now, its my first day with flutter

Comment: Same, it works , with Container but not with expanded

Comment: Nope, shall i share you the files? its just 4 files

Comment: @pskink, have posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after hours of time I found out finally, the error was in my `main.dart` file.
Initially, the code was

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './product_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main(){ 
   debugPaintSizeEnabled=true;
  runApp(MyApp());
  } 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
        accentColor: Colors.deepPurple
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Alpit anand"),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [ProductManger()],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

But when i changed to

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './product_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main(){ 
   debugPaintSizeEnabled=true;
  runApp(MyApp());
  } 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
        accentColor: Colors.deepPurple
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Alpit anand"),
          ),
          body:
          ProductManger(),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink), you really helped me out. Thanks for your time. Although I still have to find out, why it wasn't working that way.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Column(children: [ 
      Container(margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0), child: ProductControl(_addProducts)),
      Expanded(child: Products(_products))
    ]);
  }
```

To

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column: children: [ 
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0), 
        child: ProductControl(_addProducts)),
      Expanded(child: Products(_products))
    ]);
  }
```

If it does not work , Please give a look to [SingleChildeScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

Comment: Nope, nada, nothing, if u want i can share the screen on skype

Comment: I am looking in the link

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to look into it, I have posted the answer